# Блог с поддержкой LaTeX

Tags: latex

Никто не знает, есть такое или нет? Только не так, как на блогпосте, где для вставки формулы нужно сначала ее написать на стороннем сайте, там из нее генерируется графический файл, и т. д., и т. п. муторно это все.

Comment: Вам для своего пректа или активный? Redmine, JupyterHub, Emacs org-mode поддерживают LaTeX

Comment: А как понять "активный"?

Comment: Скорее всего, JupyterHub - плохое место: он находится на github, а там бо-ольшая часть команд latex просто не поддерживается.

Comment: > Emacs org-mod   не подскажите, где это? А то поиск в Гугл дает какой-то режим.

Comment: Не совсем понятна ваша цель - вы хотите развернуть свой сервис или найти уже активный, живой, запущенный "блог"? https://github.com/nakkaya/static, https://orgmode.org/manual/Embedded-LaTeX.html

Comment: У меняи есть [блог](https://matematikaandinformatika.blogspot.com/). Я хочу, чтобы, когда там пишешь сообщение, не ходить куда-то там на сторону за ссылками на фотографии на этой стороне набранных формул, а прям на моем блоге набирать коды формул и при публикации эти коды превращались бы в формулы.

Comment: У вас блог на Blogger, ищите под него расширения. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13865/how-to-use-latex-on-blogspot